# Find in files on remote server with Notepad++

Tags: ssh, notepad++, sftp, find-in-files

I have a remote Linux server, and I edit files on it over SFTP in Notepad++ using the NppFTP plugin.  When I open a file for editing, NppFTP downloads the file locally to this folder:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\NppFTP\Cache\remote_user@remote.ip.add.ress\var\www\example.com\
```

When changes are ready, I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and NppFTP uploads the file to the server.  I tab over to my browser, refresh, and see my changes.  It's a pretty nice workflow!

However, I have problems when I use the "Find in Files" tool.  If I select "Follow current doc[ument]", it points at the temp directory above.  This directory only contains the files I've selected for editing.  If I haven't opened a file for editing, it doesn't download it from the server.  It also doesn't check for modifications on the server that aren't reflected in the contents of the temp folder.

[image]

I have to either tab over to PuTTY and

```
grep -r --include=*.{php,css,js} --exclude-dir=".svn" "pattern" .
```

or download the files manually.  Neither of these options allows me to click the results in the "Find result" window and open the file to the relevant line from there.

How can I use a local editor with recursive file searches on my remote server?  I would prefer to continue to use Notepad++ and the Find In Files dialog, but am open to other options.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I've found that works is to manually download the entire remote directory to the local temp directory using, for example, WinSCP.

After downloading all the files, NppFTP works exactly as if I had selected the file and opened it in its interface, and uploads it when I save the file in Notepad++.  It searches the contents, and if I click a result in the "Find results" dialog, it opens the file to that line.